# Non-normality in MANOVA with significant planned contrasts versus non-significance in Kruskal-Wallis- A Conundrum

Tags: nonparametric, manova

I am conducting a between groups analysis for 3 groups (*N*=26, one control group and two experimental groups) with 4 dependent variables. I initially planned to conduct a MANOVA, however I am not meeting normality (significant skewness and kurtosis using *z* > 2.58) and homogeneity of variance assumptions for 2 of the DVs. Following a log transformation, one DV was corrected by the other has remained significantly skewed.

I initially decided to conduct a Kruskal-Wallis non-parametric test. However, due to a non-significant main effect I was unable to carry out post hoc contrasts. The initial MANOVA I conducted was significant on all DVs for several planned contrasts (control vs both experimental groups- one of my study's main hypotheses), however it seems I will be unable to report these findings if I choose a non-parametric test as above.

Is there any way I can

- Report these contrasts in MANOVA despite non-normality?
- Conduct planned contrasts in Kruskal-Wallis (which does not seem like an option according to Field, 2004)
- Use an alternative analysis?